# Orbit of a Weight Vector?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given some element $\phi$ of a representation $R$ of a group $G$, the orbit $G(\phi)$ of $\phi$ is defined as the set $g \phi \ \forall \  g \in G$.

We can write every element of a given representation as a weight vector $w$. **How can I compute the orbit of $w$, i.e. the set weights in this orbit?** **Specifically my problem is computing $ g w$. How does the group act on the weight vector?**

My idea was to act with the roots (that correspond to the generators of the group) on the weights. Unfortunately this way I can get every weight that corresponds to $R$, i.e. the orbit would always be the complete representation $R$. Therefore this must be wrong.

Comment: I'm not positive, but would [this earlier answer by yours truly](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/54423/11619) help you here? Assuming that you want to study the orbit of the weight under the Weyl group rather then the orbit of a vector in $R$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your issue with your idea. You are looking for the orbit of the vector, not the span of the orbit. Just because the orbit spans R doesn't mean you have done anything wrong.

Comment: And just to make sure. Not all vectors in $R$ are weight vectors (assuming a semisimple Lie group so that it makes sense to talk about weight vectors), but they often are linear combinations of weight vectors.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks for your comment. As far as I understand the Weyl orbit is different from the orbit I'm trying to compute. The orbit I'm looking for are all the weights that are connected to my initial weight trough a group transformation $g$

Comment: @WSL My problem is that the roots act like ladder operators on a given weight. That's how one can compute the weight system of a given representation in the first place. In turn this means that if I simply compute all the weights that I get from a given weight by acting on it with the roots I always get the complete weight system of the given representation. This would mean the orbit of a weight is always the complete weight system of the representation our weight lives in.

Comment: Jakob, the ladder operators are not elements of the group. They reside in the Lie algebra. Restricting myself to the semisimple case: A weight vector $v$ is a common eigenvector of a fixed maximal torus $T$. If $g\in G$ then $gv$ is a common eigenvector of another maximal torus $T'=gTg^{-1}$. For us to have $T=T'$ we cannot use an arbitrary element of $G$, but need to restrict it to a the normalizer $N=N_G(T)$. If $g\in T$ then $gv$ is a scalar multiple of $v$. To get different weights we can look at $N/T$. And $N/T$ is the Weyl group.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes in my understand the generators $T_a$ of the group (= elements of the Lie algebra) correspond to the roots, because the roots are the weights of the adjoint representation. We can write group elements $g  \in G$ as $g=e^{\alpha_a T_a}$. Therefore my idea was if I want to compute how $g$ acts on a given element of some representation (= a weight) I can compute how the generators (= roots) act on it. I know there must be sth wrong with this line of thought, because I get nonsensical results. If not through the roots, how can I compute the group action on a given weight?

Comment: In other words, most of the vectors in the orbit $Gw$ are not weight vectors. And the weights of those that are belong to the Weyl orbit of $\lambda$ Or are we talkiing apples and oranges :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Although it sounds somewhat strange, what you say makes perfect sense to me. My problem is that I don't know how I can compute $Gw$ correctly